# Not able to connect using static IP on guest OS

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, oracle-linux

I have installed Oracle Linux on a virtual box, the host is Windows 8.

When I enable static IP configuration on the guest OS which is Oracle Linux, I am not able to connect to the internet. My network settings are as shown in the enclosed screenshot.
When I switch to Automatic DHCP, I am able to connect to the internet.

[image]

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: You need to switch the interface to Bridge mode in VirtualBox. You probably have it set it NAT mode and VirtualBox is handing out the DHCP address.

Comment: @Appleoddity This does help to resolve the issue. if you post an answer, I will be very glad to accept it. Thanks a lot.